# Jquery Mobile Allow Same Page Transition - with Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I have configuration to allow same page transition in my JQuery Mobile web app.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;
});
```

It produces problem with my drop down/ popup menu.

```
<a href="#page1" data-rel="popup" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Option</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="page1">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a">
        <li><a data-rel="dialog" href="#dialog1">Dialog 1</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that clicking outside the popup will make the page blank. Removing the config `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;` solved the problem but I want to allow same page transition in my JQM web-app.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change it in the wrong point, instead of **[pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)** it should be **[mobileinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/globalconfig.html)**:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;
});
```

Basically any change to global settings must go through mobileinit event and it MUST be executed before jQuery Mobile is initialized, read more about it here: **[Working with jQuery Mobile's Auto-initialization](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)**.

So you should initialize it like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = true;
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

**EDIT :**

Then you need to cheat a bit. First you must understand that jQM popup is probably the most bugged jQM widget.

To fix your problem you should prevent popup closing when touched/clicked outside of popup (data-dismissible="false"). To close it you should add textless closing button at popup top left/right corner.

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nAtfK/
    Option

```
<div data-role="popup" id="page1" data-dismissible="false">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" style="min-width:210px;">
        <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Popup API</li>
        <li><a data-rel="dialog" href="#dialog1">Dialog 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Other solution is to switch to jQuery Mobile version 1.3.1.